# Which CPU architectures support Compare And Swap (CAS)?

Tags: multithreading, multicore, atomic, cpu-architecture

just curious to know which CPU architectures support compare and swap atomic primitives?

Answer (score 13):

Powerpc has more powerful primitives available: "lwarx" and "stwcx"

lwarx loads a value from memory but remembers the location. Any other thread or cpu that touches that location will cause the "stwcx", a conditional store instruction, to fail.

So the lwarx /stwcx combo allows you to implement atomic increment / decrement, compare and swap, and more powerful atomic operations like "atomic increment circular buffer index"

Comment: x86, too, has atomic increment/decrement (`lock inc`/`lock dec`) and atomic exchange-and-add (`xadd`).

Comment: The nice thing with lwarx and stwcx is that lock inc/lock dec are not the only things you can implement with them. They give you a building block for software transaction memory (STM) with good scalability across multiple cores.

Comment: Another bonus of load-store-exclusive is that they don't suffer from the ABA problem that can complicate some algorithms using compare-exchange or compare-and-store.  If anything touches a location between the load and store-exclusive, the store-exclusive will "know", even if the location gets rewritten with the original value.

Comment: @supercat: Very good point that I did not think of! the ABA problem is a tough one to solve without this.

Comment: The ABA problem for CXG/CAS may be avoided if the operations can operate on something large enough to include an index counter that will not overflow in any meaningful timescale. Still, load/store-exclusive offers the advantage of not requiring such a counter. LX/SX cannot emulate a true atomic CompareExchange, though in many cases compare-and-store would be an acceptable alternative. BTW, I wonder why CAS is called "compare and swap", rather than "compare and store", since the former description sounds like "compare-exchange" while the latter describes what it does.

Comment: How long is the location loaded by lwarx locked for ?

Comment: @mP.: In systems with load-linked/store-conditional instructions, the load-linked doesn't "lock" anything, but the store-conditional instruction will only perform the store if the system can guarantee that the location has not been disturbed; failure to perform the store doesn't mean the location was disturbed--merely that the system can't guarantee that it wasn't.  Properly-written code must expect that any conditional-store operation might spontaneously fail; such failures may (and generally will) affect performance, but must not affect correctness.

Comment: @mP.: To use a database analogy, imagine a database which bumps a 64-bit update counter any time *anything* is modified.  Load-linked reads the state of a record along with the update counter; store-conditional writes a record only if the update counter holds a particular value.  If everyone who wants to update the database does so by performing a load-linked and very quickly performs a store-conditional, many of those operations will succeed, but some will fail because of updates that occur to records that are not of interest.  The longer the time between load-linked and store-conditional...

Comment: ...the higher the likelihood of failure.  A common pattern is to a non-linked load, compute new data based upon old data, and then do a linked load to make sure data is still valid; if it is, then do a store-conditional.  If it does fail, do another linked load and see if the data has actually changed.  If not, try another store conditional.  If something happens to bump the update count but doesn't disturb the information of interest, one may have to retry the load-linked/store-conditional operations, but not start over from scratch.

Comment: @supercat Overflow would actually be necessary for indefinite processing, the important part is to ensure the overflow does not occur for a reasonable period of time to avoid the ABA problem.

Comment: @JAB: In some situations, rather than handling overflow it may be more practical to engineer things so that the time required for an overflow to occur would significantly exceed the amount of time during which the counter would be relevant.  Even if a 64-bit counter is incremented a billion times per second, it will take 544 years to overflow; I do not consider it unreasonable to assume that a system won't be in continuous use for 544 years (Boeing received some ridicule for the fact that their solution to the fact that their generator controllers would shut down after...

Comment: ...248 days of being on continuously was to require as a maintenance procedure that the generators be cycled off at least once every 120 days, but the only way the generators could be on for even a month would be if many other safety and maintenance procedures were skipped.  While the requirement that the generator controllers must be reset once every eight months should have been better documented, from an engineering standpoint there's no reason to deal with timer overflow beyond specifying that periodic restarts are necessary, given that such restarts are already needed for other reasons.

Answer (score 10):

Sorry for a lot of letters. :(

Almost all instructions in the x86 ISA (except so called string instructions, and maybe few others), including CMPXCHG, are atomic in the context of unicore CPU. This is because according to the x86 architecture, CPU checks for arrived interrupts after each instruction execution completion and never in the middle. As a result, interrupt request can be detected and it handling be launched only on boundary between execution of two consecutive instructions. Due to this all memory references taken by CPU during execution of single instruction are isolated and can't be interleaved by any other activities. That behavior is common for unicore and multicore CPUs. But if in the context of unicore CPU there is only one unit of the system that performs access to the memory, in the context of multicore CPU there are more then one unit of the system which performs access to the memory simultaneously. Instruction isolation isn't enough for consistency in such environment, because memory accesses made by different CPUs in the same time can interleave each other. Due to this additional protection layer must be applied to the data changing protocol. For the x86 this layer is lock prefix, that initiates atomic transaction on the system bus.

[image]

Summary: It is safe and less costly to use sync instructions like CMPXCHG, XADD, BTS, etc. without lock prefix if you assured, that the data accessed by this instruction can be accessed only by one core. If you are not assured in this, apply lock prefix to provide safety by trading off performance.

There are two major approach for hardware synchronization support by CPU:

1. Atomic transaction based.
2. Cache coherence protocol based.

No one is silver bullet. Both approaches have they advantages and disadvantages.

Atomic transactions based approach relies to the supporting of the special type of transactions on the memory bus. During such transaction only one agent (CPU core) connected to the bus is eligible to access memory. As result, on the one hand, all memory references made by the bus owner during atomic transaction are assured to be made as a single uninterruptible transaction. On the another hand all other bus agents (CPU cores) will be enforced to wait the atomic transaction completion, to get back the ability to access memory. It doesn't matter, what memory cells they want to access, even if they want to access the memory region that is not referenced by bus owner during atomic transaction. As result extensive use of lock prefixed instructions will slow down the system significantly. On the other hand, due to the fact that the bus arbiter gives access to the bus for each bus agent according to the round robin scheduling, there is a guarantee that each bus agent will have relatively fair access to the memory and all agents will be able to made progress and made it with the same speed. In addition, ABA problem come into the play in case of atomic transactions, because by its nature, atomic transactions is very short (few memory references made by single instruction) and all actions taken on memory during transaction rely only to the value of memory region, without taking into the account, is that memory region was accessed by some one else between two transactions.
Good example of atomic transaction based sync support is x86 architecture, in which lock prefixed instructions enforce CPU execute them in atomic transactions.

Cache coherence protocol based approach rely to the fact that the memory line can be cached only in the one L1 cache in the one instant of time. The memory access protocol in cache coherence system is similar to next sequence of actions:

1. CPU A store the memory line X in L1 cache. In the same time CPU B desire to access memory line X. (X --> CPU A L1)
2. CPU B issue memory line X access transaction on the bus. (X --> CPU A L1)
3. All bus agents (CPU cores) have a so called snooping agent that listen all transactions on the bus and check if memory line access to which was requested by transaction is stored in its owner CPU L1 cache. So, CPU A snooping agent detects that CPU A owns the memory line requested by CPU B. (X --> CPU A L1)
4. CPU A suspend memory access transaction issued by CPU B. (X --> CPU A L1)
5. CPU A flush the memory line requested by B from its L1 cache. (X --> memory)
6. CPU A resume previously suspended transaction. (X --> memory)
7. CPU B fetch memory line X from the memory. (X --> CPU B L1)

Thank to that protocol CPU core always access the actual data in memory, and accesses to the memory are serialized in strict order, one access in time. 
Cache coherence protocol based sync support rely to the fact, that CPU can easily detect, that the particular memory line was accessed between two time points. During the first memory access to the line X that must open transaction, CPU can mark that memory line in L1 cache must be controlled by snooping agent. In its turn snooping agent can during cache line flush in addition perform check to identify is that line is marked for control, and raise internal flag if controlled line flushed. As result, if CPU will check the internal flag during memory access that close the transaction, it will know is controlled memory line was able to be changed by someone else and conclude is transaction must be accomplished with success or must be considered as failed.
This is the way of LL\SC instruction class implementation. This approach more simple that atomic transaction and provides much more flexibility in synchronization, because much more number of different sync primitives can be build on it base in comparison with atomic transactions approach. This approach is more scalable and efficient, because it doesn't block access to the memory for all other parts of the system. And as you can see it solves the ABA problem, because it base on the fact of memory region access detection, but not on value of memory region change detection. Any access to the memory region participating in ongoing transaction will be considered as an transaction fail. And this can be good and bad in the same time, because particular algorithm can be interested only in the value of memory region and doesn't take in the account is that location was accessed by someone in the middle, until that access change the memory. In that case read of memory value in the middle will lead to false negative transaction fail. In addition that approach can lead to huge performance degradation of control flows contenting on the same memory line, because they are able to constantly steel memory line from each other, and by this preventing each other from completion transaction with success. That is really significant problem because in terminal case it can turn system in livelock.
Cache coherence protocol based sync support usually used in RISC CPU, because of it simplicity and flexibility. But it must be noted that Intel decided to support such approach for synchronization support in x86 architecture too. At last year Intel announced the Transactional Synchronization Extensions to x86 architecture that will be implemented in Haswell generation of Intel processors. In result, it looks like, the x86 will have most powerful support of synchronization and allow system developers to use advantages of both approaches.

Comment: Wow. Thank You for explanation from microscopic view

Answer (score 8):

A different and easier way to answer this question may be to list multiprocessor platforms that do NOT support a compare and swap (or a load-link/store-conditional that can be used to write one).

The only one I know of is PARISC, which only has an atomic clear word instruction.  This can be used to construct a mutex (provided one aligns the word on a 16 byte boundary).  There is no CAS on this archetecture (unlike x86, ia64, ppc, sparc, mips, s390, ...)

Comment: Older ARM is the second platform without full CAS:  http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic says about arm, pa (PA-RISC), sh they have "no native atomic instructions, but the linux kernel provides support for software atomic operations."

Answer (score 7):

A few people commented/asked about whether the "lock" prefix is needed on x86/x64 for cmpxchg. The answer is yes for multicore machines. The instruction is completely atomic for single core machines without lock.

It's been a while since I studied this stuff that deeply but I seem to remember that the instruction is technically restartable - it can abort the instruction mid-flight (if it hasn't had any side effects yet) to avoid delaying interrupt handling for too long.

Answer (score 5):

Intel x86 has this support. IBM in it's [Solaris to Linux Porting Guide](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-solar/) gives this example:

```
bool_t My_CompareAndSwap(IN int *ptr, IN int old, IN int new)
{
        unsigned char ret;

        /* Note that sete sets a 'byte' not the word */
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
                "  lock\n"
                "  cmpxchgl %2,%1\n"
                "  sete %0\n"
                : "=q" (ret), "=m" (*ptr)
                : "r" (new), "m" (*ptr), "a" (old)
                : "memory");

        return ret;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain this further? Why do you use the `lock` instruction. Is `cmpxchg` by itself atomic? Does the code above only "touch" a single memory location, or does it implement a memory fence and trigger global cache coherence protocols?

Answer (score 5):

Starting with the ARMv6 architecture ARM has the LDREX/STREX instructions that can be used to implement an atomic compare-exchange operation.

Comment: Is ARM's LDREX/STREX similar to PPC's LWARX/STWCX?

Comment: I believe so - the ARM Tech Ref manual's explanation of LDREX/STREX is rather complex (and for the PowerPC I'm going by Jeff Koftinoff's explanation) so there may well be some difference in the details.

Answer (score 4):

Just to complete the list, MIPS has Load Linked (ll) and Store Conditional (sc) instructions which load a value from memory and later conditionally store if no other CPU has accessed the location. Its true that you can use these instructions to perform swap, increment, and other operations. However the disadvantage is that with a large number of CPUs exercising locks very heavily you get into livelock: the conditional store will frequently fail and necessitate another loop to try again, which will fail, etc.

The software mutex_lock implementation can become very complicated trying to implement an exponential backoff if these situations are considered important enough to worry about. In one system I worked on with 128 cores, they were.

Comment: I agree, lock contention is something that has to be watched very carefully when using non-locking data-structures (which typically use CAS). Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 3):

The x86 and Itanium have CMPXCHG (compare and exchange)

Comment: Note to old hardware hackers, this instruction wasn't added until the i486.

Comment: that's a note to young hackers isn't it?

Comment: Is CMPXCHG an atomic operation, or do you have to use a LOCK with it?

Comment: CMPXCHG is atomic against preemption inside the single CPU, but LOCK added to it will make it atomic against cross-multiple CPU.   this is because "lock" actually locks the memory bus access by all the CPUs.   http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/50/PLN/lock.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Compare and swap was added to IBM mainframes in 1973.  It (and compare double and swap) are still on the IBM mainframes (along with more recent multi-processor functions like PLO - perform locked operation).

Comment: Supposedly CAS (Compare And Swap) is the initials of the guy who invented the instruction. "Charley".

Answer (score 2):

Sparc v9 has a cas instruction. The SPARC v9 [architecture manual](http://www.sparc.org/standards/SPARCV9.pdf) discusses the use of the CAS instruction in Annex J, look specifically at examples J.11 and J.12.

I believe the name of the instruction is actually "casa", because it can access either the current address space or an alternate. "cas" is an assembler macro which accesses the current ASI.

There is also an article on [developers.sun.com](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/atomic_sparc/) discussing the various atomic instructions which Sparc processors have implemented over the years, including cas.

Comment: What is it? Can you give a link?

Comment: Note though that x86 has double word CAS and the other non-SPARC CPUs have ll/cs - both of which solve ABA with a counter.  Single word CAS does not permit solving ABA with a counter and as such SPARC is badly disadvantaged compared to other architectures.

Comment: What about Sparc v8 or Sparc v7?