# Is it thread safe to change a variable with no calculation of previous data involved?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, global-variables

I heard it's thread unsafe to do "global_variable += individual_thread_data"; for example [without locks].

But is it thread safe if one only does "global_variable = individual_thread_data" in each thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without considering the variable type, it is not thread safe. You should use mutexes/critical sections or atomic variables.

Sometimes it useful to write a simple code which assigns variables of several types and disassemble it to see how it is going to be assigned.

Also, for a [cas-supporting architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151783/which-cpu-architectures-support-compare-and-swap-cas) you can use assembler code to simulate an atomic variable.

(Another tip: the variable should be declared as `volatile` if used in threads, to prevent the optimization done by compiler.)

Comment: Ok, I put a mutex code (of pthreads) around the global variable. It should be enough I guess. Thank you for the tip [of 'volatile'], I guess it should be common practice for mutexed variables.

Comment: No, you do not need to use `volatile` if you are using mutexes.  `pthread_mutex_lock()` and `pthread_mutex_unlock()` must necessarily act as compiler barriers.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, it's  just as unsafe (another thread may be using that variable at the same time).